# Is it possible to share the Angular 2+ core libraries over multiple applications?

Tags: angular, cdn

We have multiple Angular applications on the same platform. Today they all have there own main.js file with the Angular Core files included. Since all applications use the same Angular version we would like to extract the Angular Core code and share it (externalize it) between all the applications. This would reduce the download size. (How) is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest to refactor your 'apps' to be angular modules(lazy loaded) and all of them being part of a single angular application?

Comment: There are multiple companies building apps for the platform. There is not one application.

Comment: Is it possible to ask the vendors to develop modules instead of standalone apps. There could be wrapper angular app that lazily loads the required modules in respective paths